# Angular: Page overflows when height of both html and body is set to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm developing a SPA using Angular, and I have specified `html, body { height: 100% }` and `body { margin: 0 }` in CSS. In this situation, if I use HTML tags with default margins in a component, such as `<h1>` tag, the page will overflow.

This seems to be due to the fact that the margin of the first element of body is replaced by the margin of the body, which is different from the behavior in plain HTML. In plain HTML, the top margin of the first element is ignored, and the body never has a margin. However, this behavior is not the case in Angular (or React, to be precise).

What is the cause of this?
Also, is there any way to achieve the normal HTML behavior in Angular?

Samples in Stack Blitz are as follows:

- Plain HTML:
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-x6cd4l?file=index.html
- Angular:
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2yrmkw?file=src/app/app.component.ts
- React:
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4mdnyl?file=index.tsx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's your HTML version is missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so it's being rendered differently.  And the overflow is caused by the H1 having a top margin, causing a margin between the body and html.

Comment: As you pointed out, the plain HTML version was missing `<!DOCUTYPE html>`, so I added it. The top margin of the first element of the body is no longer ignored, but there is still a difference in overflow. Is there any way to prevent overflow in Angular?

- Modified plain HTML sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-x6cd4l?file=index.html

Comment: In the plain HTML sample above, CSS was not loaded.
In situations where CSS was working, it behaved the same as when rendered with Angular or React. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I couldn't make it with StackBlitz, so I made it with CodePen. - Re-modified plain HTML sample: https://codepen.io/yokotani/pen/abwxeNj

Comment: As I mentioned in my original comment.  H1 has a margin.  Simply set `margin-top: 0` for `h1` and the problem is no longer.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Can you post your first comment as an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's your HTML version is missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so it's being rendered differently. And the overflow is caused by the H1 having a top margin, causing a margin between the body and html.

Once you've added the doctype you can then set `margin-top: 0` for `h1` and the problem should no longer exist.